# Server not allowing POST method over ssl connection

Tags: ssl, post, server, internet-explorer-11, cloud-foundry

I am trying to make a POST request to a PHP script that I have deployed on a Pivotal PCF Instance. I have set the essential headers in the PHP script to accept cross domain requests. However, when I make a POST request from the html code shared below, I see that the GET request is sent instead of POST request. In IE 11 browser and I get `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3` error. Also, when I try to post the data from Chrome browser, I see the below request header

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
```

It looks like the server is not accepting the POST requests. I am sharing the below server side PHP script and client side html code for reference. I am not sure whether it has something to do with the scripts, server side configurations or SSL certificate.

I have already research a lot and also tried the solution provided in various posts for the similar question on Stackoverflow but none of it helped.

Approaches tried so far,

Approach 1: Using PHP script
Server side PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Method:' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
$response = array(
    'status' => 0,
    'status_message' =>'Employee Addition Failed.'
);

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['credentials'])) {
        $response = array(
            'empid' => 123,
            'emp_name' =>'Some Name',
            'method' => 'POST'
        );
    }
}

if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)) {
    $id = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } 
    $response = array(
        'empid' => 123,
        'emp_name' =>'Some Name',        
        'method' => 'GET',
        'id' => $id,
        'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'enable_post_data_reading' => ini_get('enable_post_data_reading')
    );    
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Client side html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://ui-php.apps.pcfdev.prod.demo.int/app/?id=1233",
        type:"POST",
        data:JSON.stringify({username:'Something', credentials: 'credentials'}),
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(){
            console.log('Success');
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="send">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make a call from Chrome browser, I get the below response.
[image]

Response Headers from Chrome browser:
[image]

When I make a call from IE11 browser, I see the below header being set automatically by the browser and no response is received. 
[image]

I see the below error in the console of IE11 browser:
[image]

Approach 2:
When I try to do a POST curl request, I see that the code inside the GET block from the PHP script gets executed. Below is the response from curl request.
[image]

[Note: I have set proxy in the browser, without it, I will not be able to access the PCF API]

Comment: If you look at Dev Tools in your browser, look at the network tab and confirm that a POST is being sent. When you confirm that, then your Javascript (and the browser) is working correctly. At that point, if you are not getting a POST request on your server side code, then something in between the browser and the server is changing it (a proxy or load balancer, likely).

Comment: Nothing in Cloud Foundry should modify your request method. Gorouter doesn't modify requests. Nothing in the way the PHP buildpack sets up your app should do this either, at least not intentionally. Definitely check `cf logs` to confirm. Gorouter and Apache HTTPD or Nginx, as set up by the PHP buildpack, will write access logs which will tell you the HTTP method they observe. You can use that to track down where the change is occurring.